# How to insert text before the first line if a certain word exists in the whole text with regex?

Tags: regex, replace, insert, find

I'd like to do this with regex.

Example:

Convert this(where bla can be any text):

```
bla bla blaba bla bla blablbalba
bala bla COCOA bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

To this:

```
Chocolate is unhealty!
bla bla blaba bla bla blablbalba
bala bla COCOA bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: English. I'm using "Search-Replace-DB-master" for wordpress.

Comment: @skyli I think Mureinik was referring to "Programming Language" :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for

```
(.*\n.*COCOA.*\n.*)
```

and replace by

```
Chocolate is unhealty!$1
```

`()` stores the result so you can access it later by `$1`. `.*` matches any char zero to unlimited times. `\n` matches newline.

Comment: With Regex, I forgot to include it in the question (only in a label)

Comment: can `bla bla ... ` be any text?

Comment: yes! it can be anything. I want to search for "cocoa" only.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! :) And thanks for the explanation too!